# How can I verify signature with x509 certificates?

Tags: openssl, signature, x509

I spent 2 days trying to understand how to verify xml signature, with x509 as key,without success.

Can you please explain me how to do? What information should I use to verify signature. The thing I have not understood the most, is which certificate(s) should I use to do so.

For information, I use openssl lib, in C.

Here is an example of my XML File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CompositionPlaylist xmlns="http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/429-7/2006/CPL">
  <Id>urn:uuid:7f96aa1a-16bc-4500-a3a6-d5003bbdd826</Id>
  <AnnotationText>BLACK-SMPTE_ENC</AnnotationText>
  <IssueDate>2011-12-03T15:03:28+01:00</IssueDate>
  <Issuer>Doremi Labs, Inc.</Issuer>
  <Creator>orca_wrapping 3.2.0</Creator>
  <ContentTitleText>BLACK-SMPTE_ENC</ContentTitleText>
  <ContentKind>test</ContentKind>
  <ContentVersion>
    <Id>urn:uuid:0f0d4efc-f1b5-034c-a94e-610e15fe6f2b</Id>
    <LabelText>BLACK-SMPTE_ENC</LabelText>
  </ContentVersion>
  <RatingList/>
  <ReelList>
    <Reel>
      <Id>urn:uuid:4637e047-47ce-46a5-9aa7-de3b6c5b1f82</Id>
      <AssetList>
        <MainPicture>
          <Id>urn:uuid:a06412e1-5cb5-4320-b830-b58f22796d3d</Id>
          <EditRate>24 1</EditRate>
          <IntrinsicDuration>240</IntrinsicDuration>
          <EntryPoint>0</EntryPoint>
          <Duration>240</Duration>
          <KeyId>urn:uuid:2aad5c28-216d-4e12-9819-2e9e45570fea</KeyId>
          <Hash>FaVor2hTsdL2XPKEec59lglmoCo=</Hash>
          <FrameRate>24 1</FrameRate>
          <ScreenAspectRatio>1998 1080</ScreenAspectRatio>
        </MainPicture>
        <MainSound>
          <Id>urn:uuid:e905c023-b1e5-48af-87af-86d52cb4e61b</Id>
          <EditRate>24 1</EditRate>
          <IntrinsicDuration>480</IntrinsicDuration>
          <EntryPoint>0</EntryPoint>
          <Duration>240</Duration>
          <KeyId>urn:uuid:be0aac4c-7459-444c-b1a8-5f530af964ff</KeyId>
          <Hash>fba3eWGkbugy4XvGMtW9iQsaz5Y=</Hash>
        </MainSound>
      </AssetList>
    </Reel>
  </ReelList>
  <Signer xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:X509Data>
      <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
        <ds:X509IssuerName>dnQualifier=\+LLvuYNO4YBJSp9Jjmlv8oippzQ=,CN=.DC.DMS.DC2.SMPTE,OU=DC.DOREMILABS.COM,O=DC2.SMPTE.DOREMILABS.COM</ds:X509IssuerName>
        <ds:X509SerialNumber>180</ds:X509SerialNumber>
      </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
      <ds:X509SubjectName>dnQualifier=GOnmfwzkUTxhgWRqSfMDX9wMfFo=,CN=CS.DMSJP2K-70056.DC.DC2.SMPTE,OU=DC.DOREMILABS.COM,O=DC2.SMPTE.DOREMILABS.COM</ds:X509SubjectName>
    </ds:X509Data>
  </Signer>
  <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:SignedInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
      <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
      <ds:Reference URI="">
        <ds:Transforms>
          <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></ds:Transform>
        </ds:Transforms>
        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
        <ds:DigestValue>HSqtok53pndb+m2Se8621a2ax58=</ds:DigestValue>
      </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue>gSjAym/za1Wcc2Ek65PZ5eHI3LIE8HencGJ9UL+ZVtDJnPcD
BTjRg5pb8S9GFWu9u0ozvnlCoXXc4x23B/6C4elpCz3SOJJ3z1EnU090qcp85zptd+8CDgoc
vy5IoaKyUy1xGJC2ByS3s6Qh5zmThUVTIhRn52k5gnH2N/cpXw9+ITyjCbZ9miMgxMCP2i/F
vYCPa6cYSvojXcKWZk5ARZSenrVRU4oy6M0fQnNMBSNuvscOPl8q5FthXS4VaajLVIrOrTD6
QvIL289KbDQTge5NdJrDuxPtF8Raq/L/p24FAnFyfiNWzstH9KEH9YNLNzseFVux9WPsVF0s
JzniaQ==</ds:SignatureValue>
    <ds:KeyInfo>
        <ds:X509Data>
          <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
            <ds:X509IssuerName>dnQualifier=\+LLvuYNO4YBJSp9Jjmlv8oippzQ=,CN=.DC.DMS.DC2.SMPTE,OU=DC.DOREMILABS.COM,O=DC2.SMPTE.DOREMILABS.COM</ds:X509IssuerName>
            <ds:X509SerialNumber>180</ds:X509SerialNumber>
          </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
          <ds:X509Certificate>MIIEejCCA2KgAwIBAgICALQwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwgYIx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</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
        <ds:X509Data>
          <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
            <ds:X509IssuerName>dnQualifier=RQ/53RmuLsbzgfPXGlRYmJruwMs=,CN=.DMS.DC2.SMPTE,OU=DC.DOREMILABS.COM,O=DC2.SMPTE.DOREMILABS.COM</ds:X509IssuerName>
            <ds:X509SerialNumber>2</ds:X509SerialNumber>
          </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
          <ds:X509Certificate>MIIEdjCCA16gAwIBAgIBAjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADB/MSEw
HwYDVQQKExhEQzIuU01QVEUuRE9SRU1JTEFCUy5DT00xGjAYBgNVBAsTEURDLkRPUkVNSUxBQlMu
Q09NMRcwFQYDVQQDEw4uRE1TLkRDMi5TTVBURTElMCMGA1UELhMcUlEvNTNSbXVMc2J6Z2ZQWEds
UlltSnJ1d01zPTAeFw0wNzAxMDEwMDAwMDBaFw0yNTEyMzEyMzU5NTlaMIGCMSEwHwYDVQQKExhE
QzIuU01QVEUuRE9SRU1JTEFCUy5DT00xGjAYBgNVBAsTEURDLkRPUkVNSUxBQlMuQ09NMRowGAYD
VQQDExEuREMuRE1TLkRDMi5TTVBURTElMCMGA1UELhMcK0xMdnVZTk80WUJKU3A5SmptbHY4b2lw
cHpRPTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAMUyBakS7Eb79G3ZFMZ4zOOn/cZ3
qJcck+MAMwjwV8LkK303uBv51cXYNWxalMQQ6h1iPAu6si9RR9XNLGqakHFLUfjt0eC8VJ5/YaC+
DvVq1j9iM5/Jz+CjSqkOlrzXbX92HyMNE0hjCGa4WU6oyRCzFvPZclOI5a2LDKOxC/ngD0LomWjo
MDP7BSkUUzqQnZ2fRuXdOgAfzWm+hBxruWcyEqSGwmV93YBnoHB2WpxVfD+Ztinnp/NJKCadiKf/
sSQpPoqe4j97gY+Zw2DtgT6wddx97ZtCf10QASF5hXgKyCku6O7IlGLroM4TUOldrTClNjR2xSGc
THxcxOltUQcCAwEAAaOB+DCB9TATBgNVHRMBAf8ECTAHAQH/AgIA7TALBgNVHQ8EBAMCAQYwHQYD
VR0OBBYEFPiy77mDTuGASUqfSY5pb/KIqac0MIGxBgNVHSMEgakwgaaAFEUP+d0Zri7G84Hz1xpU
WJia7sDLoYGKpIGHMIGEMSEwHwYDVQQKExhEQzIuU01QVEUuRE9SRU1JTEFCUy5DT00xGjAYBgNV
BAsTEURDLkRPUkVNSUxBQlMuQ09NMRwwGgYDVQQDExMuUFJPRFVDVFMuREMyLlNNUFRFMSUwIwYD
VQQuExxwa0NCOWo1S3JBam5kaGNCa2MzZk9kZkwvQlE9ggEEMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IBAQCd
l6G6uFf9+waSrTQqG946Ff1t0b1ANkI6IQQo2sq15aArKjehmrCJzctBfFm3vQj1KlRBI191Mj2m
5Oh/sxcwtG40bSzFeyGZPg9zKA2Cd8oRdw35/8ZLnP96Z/rCxoGNVJAmy9EP8jP9AT/bOk50KvZ/
wo//VN/pscoDrDCaZVLNPAkTdsMNWy+YpV9cnzUGx73jK/iMao++GQ/SEWssBHhjxn3oHWiZi4Xt
ykib8XQqQjyKu4c66jDwu6Ct+MVqUd7ZFPTFListIamu55RnpTXhDKkoN8fIunBsWOs9Kbqbxglx
4zsyE0AGuj2nDstRBWLRy+5SlCByTIKp/PL/</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
        <ds:X509Data>
          <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
            <ds:X509IssuerName>dnQualifier=pkCB9j5KrAjndhcBkc3fOdfL/BQ=,CN=.PRODUCTS.DC2.SMPTE,OU=DC.DOREMILABS.COM,O=DC2.SMPTE.DOREMILABS.COM</ds:X509IssuerName>
            <ds:X509SerialNumber>4</ds:X509SerialNumber>
          </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
          <ds:X509Certificate>MIIEdDCCA1ygAwIBAgIBBDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADCBhDEh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</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
        <ds:X509Data>
          <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
            <ds:X509IssuerName>dnQualifier=a/wUIHLuFW7RKXpNQGmQ966xOv8=,CN=.ROOT.DC2.SMPTE,OU=DC.DOREMILABS.COM,O=DC2.SMPTE.DOREMILABS.COM</ds:X509IssuerName>
            <ds:X509SerialNumber>2</ds:X509SerialNumber>
          </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
          <ds:X509Certificate>MIIEdjCCA16gAwIBAgIBAjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADCBgDEh
MB8GA1UEChMYREMyLlNNUFRFLkRPUkVNSUxBQlMuQ09NMRowGAYDVQQLExFEQy5ET1JFTUlMQUJT
LkNPTTEYMBYGA1UEAxMPLlJPT1QuREMyLlNNUFRFMSUwIwYDVQQuExxhL3dVSUhMdUZXN1JLWHBO
UUdtUTk2NnhPdjg9MB4XDTA3MDEwMTAwMDAwMFoXDTI1MTIzMTIzNTk1OVowgYQxITAfBgNVBAoT
GERDMi5TTVBURS5ET1JFTUlMQUJTLkNPTTEaMBgGA1UECxMRREMuRE9SRU1JTEFCUy5DT00xHDAa
BgNVBAMTEy5QUk9EVUNUUy5EQzIuU01QVEUxJTAjBgNVBC4THHBrQ0I5ajVLckFqbmRoY0JrYzNm
T2RmTC9CUT0wggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQDTXmBvZYW1jYsr8GaPzJeD
zeWN+Vus/RDVdaWQ9hLXKw2nLjNFNX+RYB76QiugCGUwBZ71kOL0RQ6kSAkz9FBQGYca9sh2imTc
pEuw/qjbHxClO7DNyd0af5oYtZdopBBy71ksrUWOIFeKgfa1C3iLKJWVeTDZll4s78Xzo0hdQVwF
oFyVRiQRkyr2urj0euMMcykBD5KD+hjKNpxZukzxu8VKKBSJwjifL4SsmV+zsTDJH/nRaySnhLCB
L+aO7MF6d4DF+ANKcD5LX6CQW3NIqPHhdPFC+lAol2/6sPBkbnFEfbWiHbDHS34LJaWaLkqJ3tt/
/ETe6FZe761vkeUbAgMBAAGjgfQwgfEwEwYDVR0TAQH/BAkwBwEB/wICAO8wCwYDVR0PBAQDAgEG
MB0GA1UdDgQWBBSmQIH2PkqsCOd2FwGRzd8518v8FDCBrQYDVR0jBIGlMIGigBRr/BQgcu4VbtEp
ek1AaZD3rrE6/6GBhqSBgzCBgDEhMB8GA1UEChMYREMyLlNNUFRFLkRPUkVNSUxBQlMuQ09NMRow
GAYDVQQLExFEQy5ET1JFTUlMQUJTLkNPTTEYMBYGA1UEAxMPLlJPT1QuREMyLlNNUFRFMSUwIwYD
VQQuExxhL3dVSUhMdUZXN1JLWHBOUUdtUTk2NnhPdjg9ggEBMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IBAQCd
sDTq1a3Q96o8ShsyKmEKVUCNnX6ez5XcVg5LXb8QJxXzLD+ffbf15Jj201iElpPQCNU9QHNOOoR9
IoObGZBOLi5ekMhfpfffcpwkwmq3nmb3h6WPLU7PAxLYcE3nNZdbv5QocblNs3e4Ecc3nK2bIS0K
9/e+75UT6wfOCWWCF+AHQt+1Uej6G2f2yZJ5aWqeOv3mqXEtWV8W/iiUEhz6pONdb8Vs0Bhn6FMa
jjTkpSVaC/w7W38htkG0Nk9T5Lf/TdIQHjoALB12suLTZymj8hq53PVxIN+aa0cboVE0PEtwYI5J
tIY/GaHgNIVKoTRvgq7YXTVnvGqgolL1zwDx</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
        <ds:X509Data>
          <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
            <ds:X509IssuerName>dnQualifier=a/wUIHLuFW7RKXpNQGmQ966xOv8=,CN=.ROOT.DC2.SMPTE,OU=DC.DOREMILABS.COM,O=DC2.SMPTE.DOREMILABS.COM</ds:X509IssuerName>
            <ds:X509SerialNumber>1</ds:X509SerialNumber>
          </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
          <ds:X509Certificate>MIIEcjCCA1qgAwIBAgIBATANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADCBgDEh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</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
  </ds:Signature>
</CompositionPlaylist>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: OpenSSL won't help you in verifying XML signatures. You need to use some external library that supports XMLDSig.

Answer (score 0):

You should (actually must) not write XML signature verification from scratch because it is difficult and error-prone. Use a library like `xmlsec`: https://www.aleksey.com/xmlsec/.